How to cover thermal vias in design spark pcb
I am trying to cover the vias on my PCB using the solder mask however when I upload the PCB to a manufacturer's website the vias are not covered. I am using DesignSpark PCB software
There is a post in a forum from 2019 on how to cover vias however I cannot get it to work.
Do I expect the mask to fully cover the thermal vias or is the current configuration correct?



We need to know what software and settings were used to generate the gerbers. Have you checked the gerbers yourself with a program like viewmate?

I have only checked it on some online gerber viewers, I have edited the question to include my solder and paste mask settings.

Check your gerber files with Gerbv. You should look into your solder mask layers. If the vias tented you would not see any holes on the solder masks.

You need to make sure it's not the viewer, so use a good one.

It turns out the software I use has the tented vias functionality behind a subscription paywall, do you know free alternatives to this?

The PCB manufacturer might supply such software. Or, have you looked at KiCad?
